# ¿Cómo sacar el último objeto de una cola?

Tags: java, poo, objeto, queue

Yo tengo una cola `Queue cola` de movimiento en que cada movimiento es un Objeto que contiene una Celda con posición **x,y**, y  quería acceder el último movimiento e imprimirlo en pantalla. ¿Cómo lo hago? Saludos. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Queue<String> object = new LinkedList<String>();

        //Añadimos un elemento de lo contrario puede ocurrir una excepción.
        object.add("A");

        /*
          poll nos devuelve el ultimo elemento que fue añadido
          a la cola y lo remueve (recuerda que Queue es una estructura) de
          tipo FIFO por lo tanto el primero que entra es el ultimo
          en salir, así que si obtenemos el primer elemento en la cola
          enrealidad estariamos obteniendo el ultimo que fue añadido.
        */
        System.out.println(object.poll());

        //Si no quieres removerlo usa peek:

        //System.out.println(object.peek());
    }

}
```

Si, puede parecer solo codigo, pero es que realmente no hay mucho que explicar, salvo que estamos creando una lista de strings para usarla:

```
Queue<String> object = new LinkedList<String>();
```

y le añadimos algo para poder usar el metodo poll o peek:

```
object.add("A");
```

Comment: La cola Queue puede usar la interfaz linked list de esta forma, así podras mezclar Queue con linkedList y usar los metodos de linkedList: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-interface-java/

Comment: En tu caso como tienes una cola de objetos y no una cola de strings ya sabes que hacer, en vez de usar una cola de strings usar una cola de tus objetos, por ejemplo si estas usando una cola de Points.